# Limit the number of check-boxes allowed to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

```
function CountChecks(whichlist,forarray,maxchecked,latestcheck) {
// An array containing the id of each checkbox to monitor. 
//   List the id of each checkbox in the set. If more than 
//   one set, list other sets in their own arrays. The
//   array name to use is passed to this function.


*// THIS PART IMPORTANT*//


var listone = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");


*// THIS PART IMPORTANT*//



// End of customization.
var iterationlist;
eval("iterationlist="+whichlist);
var count = 0;
for( var i=0; i<iterationlist.length; i++ ) {
   if( document.getElementById(iterationlist[i]).checked == true) { count++; }
   if( count > maxchecked ) { latestcheck.checked = false; }
   }
if( count > maxchecked ) {
   alert('Sorry, only ' + maxchecked + ' may be checked.');
   }
}
```

This is you can see CHECKBOX CHECK LIMITER.. And you can see works with function. I wanna do send this to js file from the page.. but Its not very functional becouse of array part. It has to create array's own by own.. I add the variable function part 'forarray'.. I dont know javascript and Im asking you it has to be like this when it create own arrays.

```
var {whichlist variable} = new Array({forarray variable list});
```

And HTML code like this.

```
  <p>
Check up to 3 sizes:<br>
<input id='1' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" onclick="CountChecks('listone','1',3,this)" value="2x2">2x2 
<input id='2' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" onclick="CountChecks('listone','2',3,this)" value="2x2.5">2x2.5 
<input id='3' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" onclick="CountChecks('listone','3',3,this)" value="2x3">2x3 
<input id='4' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" onclick="CountChecks('listone','4',3,this)" value="2.5x2.5">2.5x2.5 
<input id='5' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" onclick="CountChecks('listone','5',3,this)" value="2.5x3">2.5x3 
<input id='6' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" onclick="CountChecks('listone','6',3,this)" value="3x3">3x3
</p>

<p>
Check up to 2 colors:<br>
<input id='7' type="checkbox" name="favoritecolor[]" onclick="CountChecks('listtwo','7',2,this)" value="red">Red 
<input id='8' type="checkbox" name="favoritecolor[]" onclick="CountChecks('listtwo','8',2,this)" value="gold">Gold 
<input id='9' type="checkbox" name="favoritecolor[]" onclick="CountChecks('listtwo','9',2,this)" value="green">Green 
<input id='10' type="checkbox" name="favoritecolor[]" onclick="CountChecks('listtwo','10',2,this)" value="silver">Silver 
<input id='11' type="checkbox" name="favoritecolor[]" onclick="CountChecks('listtwo','11',2,this)" value="blue">Blue 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do all of that. All you need to do is pass a reference to the element into the function and then use its name to query a list of its siblings. Count the number of checked boxes and prevent any others from being checked.

```
<p>
    Check up to 3 sizes:<br>
    <input id='1' type="checkbox" name="listone" onclick="javascript:checkNumChecked(this, 3)"
        value="2x2">2x2
    <input id='2' type="checkbox" name="listone" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,3)" value="2x2.5">2x2.5
    <input id='3' type="checkbox" name="listone" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,3)" value="2x3">2x3
    <input id='4' type="checkbox" name="listone" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,3)" value="2.5x2.5">2.5x2.5
    <input id='5' type="checkbox" name="listone" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,3)" value="2.5x3">2.5x3
    <input id='6' type="checkbox" name="listone" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,3)" value="3x3">3x3
</p>
<p>
    Check up to 2 colors:<br>
    <input id='7' type="checkbox" name="listtwo" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,2)" value="red">Red
    <input id='8' type="checkbox" name="listtwo" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,2)" value="gold">Gold
    <input id='9' type="checkbox" name="listtwo" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,2)" value="green">Green
    <input id='10' type="checkbox" name="listtwo" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,2)" value="silver">Silver
    <input id='11' type="checkbox" name="listtwo" onclick="checkNumChecked(this,2)" value="blue">Blue
</p>
<script>
    function checkNumChecked(ele, limit) {
        var ct = 0, siblings = document.getElementsByName(ele.name), checked = 0;
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            checked += (siblings[ct].checked) ? 1 : 0
            if (checked > limit) {
                siblings[ct].checked = false
                alert('Sorry, only ' + limit + ' item(s) may be checked.');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, alerts are annoying to end users. A much better way of doing this is to disable the other check boxes once the limit has been reached and re-enable them when a box is unchecked.

```
<script>
    function checkNumChecked(ele, limit) {
        var ct = 0, siblings = document.getElementsByName(ele.name), checked = 0;
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            checked += (siblings[ct].checked) ? 1 : 0
        }
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            siblings[ct].disabled = siblings[ct].checked ? false : (checked == limit) ? true : false
        }
    }
</script>
```

To have the same, but make it work using only ids you can do the following:

```
<script>
    function checkNumChecked(ele, limit) {
        var ct = 0, siblings = [], checked = 0, item_num = parseInt(ele.id),
        sct = (item_num < 7) ? 1 : 7, ect = (item_num < 7) ? 6 : 11;
        for (ct = sct; ct <= ect; ct++) {
            siblings.push(document.getElementById(ct));
        }
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            checked += (siblings[ct].checked) ? 1 : 0
        }
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            siblings[ct].disabled = siblings[ct].checked ? false : (checked == limit) ? true : false
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If this works for you, please be sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons.

Comment: Its great. It works and its better than alerts.. Thanks but I just 1 thing for you. in the original of my checkboxes name section will be all same. can we do this on ID beside NAME?

Comment: Using the element names is better than using Ids. However, if you use a naming convention on the Id such as listone_1, _2, etc... Then in a loop you can push each element into an array first with getElementById with the unique Id being "listone_" + ct.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rp2ojgmt/ can you look at this This have to work with id But I couldnt on javascript...

Comment: Its becouse I ll work with PHP later too. if name would stable much better for me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196506/checbox-limiter-disabled-problems     can you look at this I have a problem with your code..