# Checbox Limiter disabled problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="malzeme1[]" checked="" disabled="" id="checkboxExample1" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample1">Soğan<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="malzeme1[]" id="checkboxExample3" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample3">Soğanx<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="malzeme1[]" id="checkboxExample4" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample4">Soğanc<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="malzeme1[]" id="checkboxExample5" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample5">Soğanxc<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>

<script>
  function checkNumChecked(ele, limit) {
    var ct = 0,
      siblings = document.getElementsByName(ele.name),
      checked = 0;
    for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
      checked += (siblings[ct].checked) ? 1 : 0
    }
    for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
      siblings[ct].disabled = siblings[ct].checked ? false : (checked == limit) ? true : false
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is mine Checkbox Limiter. For example it ll other checkboxes going disabled when I pick 2 checkbox. But there is a problem here when I after uncheck 1 checkbox forexample. It will remove original disabled="" checkbox too. It dont have to remove original disabled="" code

Answer (score 0):

What I have done here in order to permanently disable the check box you want the code to leave alone is to use a custom data attribute "data-permdisable". This tells the code to skip making any changes to the element.

Also, I should point out that you should have checked="checked" and disabled="disabled" as a matter of form.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="malzeme1[]" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="checkboxExample1"
    onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)" data-permdisable="true">
<label for="checkboxExample1">
    Soğan<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="malzeme1[]" id="checkboxExample3" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample3">
    Soğanx<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="malzeme1[]" id="checkboxExample4" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample4">
    Soğanc<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="malzeme1[]" id="checkboxExample5" onclick="checkNumChecked(this, 2)">
<label for="checkboxExample5">
    Soğanxc<b class="product-subtitlex"> | + 1 ₺</b>
</label>
<script>
    function checkNumChecked(ele, limit) {
      var ct = 0,
      siblings = document.getElementsByName(ele.name),
      checked = 0;
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            checked += ((siblings[ct].getAttribute("data-permdisable") == "true") ? 0 : ((siblings[ct].checked) ? 1 : 0))
        }
        for (ct = 0; ct <= siblings.length - 1; ct++) {
            siblings[ct].disabled = (siblings[ct].getAttribute("data-permdisable") == "true") ? 
                siblings[ct].disabled : siblings[ct].checked ? false : (checked == limit) ? true : false
        }
    }
</script>
```